# Get disk quota when not administrator?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, quota

I'm logged into uBuntu 14.04 LTS at the University. After several hours of working in nvcc (cpp compiler for nVidia CUDA C), editing .cu (CUDA cpp) and make files in gedit I suddenly get a "Disk quota exceeded" error.

Huh?

I searched online and found that commands "df -h" and "du -sh" should show me my disk quota. But when I run either of these in Terminal, Terminal hangs and I have to kill it. I'm assuming this is because I don't have rights to run these commands. There is no error message, just a hang. Normal Terminal commands like "ls" and "mkdir" work fine.

The IT department have gone home for the evening...how do I correct this problem and/or see what my quota is?

#### UPDATE!

I had been searching for programming answers in Google Chrome...and had a few crashes of Chrome just prior to this happening. I suspected temporary internet files were part of the problem. So I removed a few local files, reloaded Chrome, cleared all history ("From the beginning of time"), closed Chrome. Then tried the "quota" command suggested in the comments by @mark kirby (which failed due to not being installed)...then I tried "df -h" again and it worked! Don't think it was trying "quota" that did it. Perhaps I was so close to my limit that tmp files required for "df" could not be created.

Comment: Related? http://serverfault.com/questions/62837/how-can-i-check-remaining-disk-quota Try it and let us know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, `du -sh` takes a long time to execute, because it has to look at all files in all subdirectories all the way down to find the size of the files. How long did you wait?

`df -h` (I'd use `df -h .`) should return quickly. Again, what do you mean by "hang"?

You can recover some disk space by removing object (`*.o`) files, which I assume you can recreate through your `.cu`s and `Makefile`s. `find . -type f -name '*.o' -ls` will show them to you. Replace `-ls` with `-print0 | xargs -0 rm` to delete them all. Read `man nvcc` to find other leftover temporary files.

How many levels of source file backup do you keep?

You can use `gzip` (`man gzip`) to compress files you are not using at the moment to regain some space.

`quota --human-readable` (and `man quota`) will show your disk quota. `du` will show your disk usage (`man du`). `df` (`man df`) will display disk volume information.

Comment: Waited at least 20s for each command. After deleting several personal files and then clearing the Chrome cache, both commands return fairly quickly. And you're right, "df -h" does return slightly more quickly. Thanks for the tips about deleting and re-generating *.0 files. Will try that when I'm next on uBuntu at the University.